# Type CodeDomProvider is missing in Xamarin Forms Shared Project

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have created a Xamarin Forms Shared Project.

In the System.CodeDom.Compiler namespace are only 2 classes: GeneratedCodeAttribute and IndentedTextWriter. All other classes are missing.

My Environment:
* Windows 8.1
* Visual Studio Community 2015

Comment: That means the class you're looking for isn't supported by your current profile. I'm not familiar with that assembly. It's possible the class you're looking for doesn't even exist on Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android. If it's related to compiling code at runtime, that's specifically forbidden on iOS and not implemented.

Comment: I've removed the iOS Project, Now is only Android Project and the Shared Project in the solution. But it dont work, whether in the Shared Project nor in the Android Project.